# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.version.split') in react-native

Tags: react-native

After upgrading the RN to 0.62.2 then it failed and then shows the above evaluating 'process.version.split'.

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'process.version.split')

The issue is with the rn-nodeify

[image]

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "postinstall": "sh fix-amplify-jank.sh && ./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install --hack --yarn"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "url": "^0.10.3",
    "util": "^0.10.4",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4"
  },
```

Comment: enter this on terminal export version=0.0.1 and start metro bundler again

Comment: did you know on which file error is coming from?

Comment: No, my understanding is it is coming from rn-nodeify

Comment: yes you are right. can you try this in root App.js process.env.version="0.0.1"

Comment: can you add package.json in question?

Comment: I can't able to add full package.json. So I added the above

Comment: rn-nodeify --install "process" --hack add process and let me know

Comment: Yes I have tried with the above. But it raising another issue with vm and so on

Comment: error: Error: Unable to resolve module `crypto` from `node_modules/sjcl/sjcl.js`: crypto could not be found within the project.

Comment: https://github.com/tradle/rn-nodeify#example-workflow

Comment: yarn add crypto

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just added

```
/*<replacement>*/
var process = require("process");   // THIS LINE
var pna = require('process-nextick-args');
/*</replacement>*/
```

in node_modules\readable-stream\lib\ _stream_writable.js

Comment: looks like it worked for me after installing a few libraries

Comment: @ichimaru, you can search for this lines in the whole project and check which of the ```process``` variable has not been assigned with a value

Comment: Where in the file did you add this? 

and did you add those 4 lines, or just the line that says "// THIS LINE"...?

i've searching for parts of that 4 lines and nothing was found so assume you add all 4 lines, but where about in the file?

Comment: This is an old thread and I am not sure if this issue is still existing. Yes only the line says "//   THIS LINE"

Comment: I am having the issue right now, so it certainly exists in some form or shape. I am building a react native project using multiple modules including crypto (if this helps at all)

Comment: Also, to add the only line that has // THIS LINE, it implies that the other lines exist in the file, but they do not. :/

Comment: This worked for me and my colleagues at that time. And now it has been awhile since I posted this solution. Probably the library got updated